# SQL query to get value having multiple in the same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table with many columns like `col1, col2, col3, id, variantId, col4, col5` etc

However I am only interested in `id, variantId` which look like this:

```
+----------+-----------+
| id       | variantId |
+----------+-----------+
| a        | 11        |
| a        | 12        | 
| b        | 31        | 
| c        | 41        |
| c        | 54        | 
| d        | abc       | 
| e        | xyz       | 
| e        | xyz       | 
+----------+-----------+
```

I need distinct ids which having count of distinct variantId more than once
In this case I would only get a and c

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. It's important to know what RDBMS you are using :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(variant_id) <> max(variant_id);
```

You can also use:

```
having count(distinct variant_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with group by having clause

```
select id
from table
group by id
having count(distinct variant_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more efficiently with EXISTS:

```
select distinct t.id
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and variantid <> t.variantid
)
```